# Data Pipeline: URL request in Google Cloud Function ends with "crash" on VPC Connector

Tags: google-cloud-platform, proxy, google-cloud-functions, data-pipeline

I am having a small problem with my Cloud Function that crashes the message is

> Function execution took 242323 ms, finished with status: 'crash'

**My Setup**
There are two GCP projects set up, One is managed by Department A, I work in Department B and I am getting access to a server that is set up on Department A's GCP project.

The Department A GCP project sits behind our internal network, and I am accessing a server on that project via VPC Connector.

On my department B GCP project, I use Cloud Scheduler, Cloud Pub/Sub, Cloud Function and Cloud Storage.

**Workflow**
Cloud Scheduler publishes once a day a message to a pub/sub-topic.
A Cloud Function subscribes to the pub/sub-topic, when a new message arrives at the pub/sub-topic, the Cloud Function will initiate an HTTP request to the server on the Department A GCP Server. The request made to the server initiates a query and returns data that is stored in CLoud Storage as a .csv file.

I have several URL that I have scheduled to run during a morning period, only on give me a problem as it takes the longest time to execute, all other URLs that I execute are completing with status OK, and the files are stored in Cloud Storage.

This specific URL that I have a problem with always crashes around 242323 ms, even if my Cloud Function is set to 540 seconds.

[image]

To mention the other URLs that works are all completed before 242323 ms mark.

Viewing the log I can see that the troublesome URL that crash the Cloud Function, the message is ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

I am using python "requests" to make the HTTP Request.

In Department A we use a proxy server in their GCP Project which the VPC-Connector has been paired with.

We can use cURL to make the HTTP request from the Department B GCP project, with cURL we can without any problem complete the request to the URL that we have a problem with using a Cloud Function.

The issue is that the request from the Cloud Function gets terminated before the end of the Cloud Functions execution time of 540 seconds. I tested the proxy and it has a timeout of 15 minutes, which is more than sufficient for the Cloud Function.

It may be an issue with the VPN Connector, I can not see any settings that are related to the hangup, I'm hoping someone here has an idea on what to look for.
[image]

Comment: The network schema is quite confuse for me. Do you have a schema to make it clearer?

Comment: HI, @guillaumeblaquiere I have added a diagram to explain how the network is set up. I use a cloud function with a VPC connector to access a Proxy on another Google Project to make a URL request from a server, the request can take up to 9 minutes, I have tested it from the cmd line by using curl, I know how long the request takes. With curl I can call the file I want to extract and I get the whole file, via the cloud function it always crashes at the 4 minutes mark,  with Connection reset by peer.